# Is there a better way to check if a file is older than X?

Tags: vb.net

I am currently using this code:

```
(Now - dctFile.LastWriteTime).TotalMinutes > DeleteAgeInDays * 1440
```

Is there a more precise way? I know I could use `.TotalMilliseconds`and multiply by 86400000, but it seems inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`.AddDays`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.adddays?view=netcore-3.1) method...

```
If dtcFile.LastWriteTime.AddDays(DeleteAgeInDays) < Date.Now Then
```

That should be good enough for the precision you require... but if you wanted it to just check based on the date (and not the time as well)...

```
If dtcFile.LastWriteTime.AddDays(DeleteAgeInDays).Date < Date.Today Then
```

Comment: To be more standard .NET and less VB6, the first code snippet should use `Date.Now` and the second should use `Date.Today`. The `Now` you're using is the VB6 holdover from the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime` module.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - I've always used `DateTime.Now` in my code and didn't actually realised you could use just `Now` until I read the OP's question... so I replicated it from their question. But I think you're right, and changed them both